# Allow users to vote to migrate a question from meta.codereview to main

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, migration, meta

This question happened; https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6970/a-good-way-to-remove-duplicate-code-without-violating-page-object-model - it's a regular Code Review question that landed on meta.

And I'd like to be able to vote for such questions to be migrated to main.

Can this be made possible, or is there a reason why this shouldn't be allowed?

Comment: That page has been deleted after I asked if they posted on the wrong site. (Which they did)

Comment: I have too much privs and no sock puppet to test this... can you (or *someone*) confirm the VTC dialog (say, on this question) doesn't allow migrating to main? Editing this post with a screenshot of the migration targets dialog would be nice. I remember in old CR beta days we could migrate from main to meta, but I can't recall if the other way around was available at all.

Comment: @Mat'sMug http://i.stack.imgur.com/Yrbwl.png Those are my options

Comment: @Pimgd it's under Off-Topic > Belongs on another SE site... apparently currently a [mod-only thing](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qJClW.png).

Answer (score 4):

There's no option for users to migrate from meta to main, because that only ever happens once in a blue moon - there's theoretically no solid grounds to enable that migration path.

The current way to migrate from meta to main, is to custom-flag for moderator attention.

---

Looking at migration stats for meta (are those accessible with 10K privs?), looking at meta-to-main migrations:

- 1 question was migrated in the last 90 days
- 2 so far in 2016
- 12 in 2015 (9 in the first quarter)
- 4 in 2014
- 6 in 2013
- 6 in 2012
- 7 in 2011

I think Q1-2015 was just weird, IMO 1-2 migrations per *quarter* wouldn't be enough to warrant a migration path.

On the other hand, I'm all for community-driven moderation, so I'm totally for it anyway - there's a migration path from main to meta already, and that migration path is even more seldom:

- 1 in 2016
- 2 in 2015
- 0 in 2014
- 2 in 2013
- 2 in 2012
- 2 in 2011

In light of these stats, I say go for it.